# FFmpeg запись видео с RPi picamera

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

Пытаюсь записать видео с RPi picamera с помощью следующей команды и не работает

```
raspivid -t 50000 -fps 25 -b 500000 -vf -o - | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec copy -an -f lavfi -r 25 -t 50000 -pix_fmt yuv420p recording-1.mp4
```

логи выдают следующие

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ raspivid -t 50000 -fps 25 -b 500000 -vf -o - | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec copy -an -f lavfi -r 25 -t 50000 -pix_fmt yuv420p recording-1.mp4
ffmpeg version N-77945-gd6b3062 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 13.100 / 55. 13.100
  libavcodec     57. 22.100 / 57. 22.100
  libavformat    57. 21.101 / 57. 21.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 25.100 /  6. 25.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, h264, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
[NULL @ 0x1f1b580] Requested output format 'lavfi' is not a suitable output format
recording-1.mp4: Invalid argument
```

Если же записывать с помощью

```
raspivid -t 50000 -fps 25 -b 500000 -vf -o - | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec copy -an -f flv -r 25 -t 50000 -pix_fmt yuv420p recording-3.flv
```

все работает, но к сожалению мне этот способ не подходит, так как конечный файл должен быть `mp4`.

В чем я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin прошу прощения

Comment: ffmpeg явно говорит, что он не знает такого формата как lavfi. Возможные варианты - собрать ffmpeg самостоятельно или посмотреть на avconv (это тот же ffmpeg, только собран немного по другому и с своими патчами).

Comment: @KoVadim ffmpeg собран самостоятельно ибо для него отсутствует установка ffmpeg через apt-get; до-установить lavfi никак?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lavfi` поддерживается только как input device:

```
lavfi indev AVOptions:
  -graph             <string>     .D...... set libavfilter graph
  -graph_file        <string>     .D...... set libavfilter graph filename
  -dumpgraph         <string>     .D...... dump graph to stderr
```

об этом говорит буква единственная буква `D`.

Попробуйте так:

```
raspivid -t 50000 -fps 25 -b 500000 -vf -o - | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec copy -an -r 25 -t 50000 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mp4 recording-1.mp4
```

или так:

```
raspivid -t 50000 -fps 25 -b 500000 -vf -o - | ffmpeg -f h264 -framerate 25 -i - -vcodec copy -an -r 25 -t 50000 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mp4 recording-1.mp4
```

Пояснения:

1. Первый вариант заменяет формат `lavfi` (который, к слову, нужен только для того, что бы в качестве входа задавать не файл, сетевой ресурс или устройство, а граф фильтров, причём фильтр сам может прочитать данные из одного или нескольких источников либо генерировать оные) на `mp4` и просто переносит задание формата ближе в заданию выходного файла (хотя, в общем случае, правильнее делать так, как у автора, особенно если выходов несколько).
2. Второй вариант, в дополнение к первому, форсирует формат входных данных `h264` и указывает частоту кадров.

Comment: спасибо, оба способа работают